# WARNING: conversion missing in backend epub3 for toc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-epub3

I'm using asciidoctor-pdf to create a PDF, and it is working nicely.
But when I use asciidoctor-epub3 to convert it to an epub it shows a warning message:

> asciidoctor: WARNING: conversion missing in backend epub3 for toc

However, the toc is added in the generated epub and I cannot figure out why I'm seeing this warning.

This is the minimal .adoc file to reproduce the problem.

```
= Book title
:doctype: book
:toc: macro

toc::[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asciidoctor-epub3 [added support for inline TOC](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-epub3/pull/342) in v 1.5.0, honoring the `:toc:` attribute.

If you use set `:toc:` attribute your epub will have an inline table of contents just after the cover/frontmatter page.

But, the support for custom placed TOC [is still in progress](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-epub3/issues/344). So, if you set `:toc: macro` and then use it with `toc::[]` to place your TOC in a custom location, it will be ignored and a warning message will be shown during compilation.

> asciidoctor: WARNING: conversion missing in backend epub3 for toc

So, despite this warning your TOC is still placed in your epub but in a fixed position.

To avoid this warning you can wrap your toc code with a conditional:

```
= Book title
:doctype: book
:toc: macro

//...

ifdef::backend-pdf[]
// add custom placed toc only in pdf
toc::[]
endif::[]
```